# How to check if an Discord Channel has a parent in JDA

Tags: java, discord, bots, discord-jda

I was wondering if I could list up all channels in a discord server. My Problem is: I don't know how to check if the Channel has a parent category!

Here's what I already tried:

```
for(TextChannel tc : guild.getTextChannels()) {
     if(tc.getParent() != null) {
     tc.sendMessage("Hello").queue();
     }
}
```

I think the problem is that you can't get something from something that doesn't exist => tc.getParent() doesn't exist so I can't check if it is null or not.

Comment: Your code should work. I’ve checked the doc and if the channel doesn’t have any category, getParent() returns null.

Comment: Do you still need an answer?

Comment: No, I found out, that I just used an outdated version